# How can I make line chart with uneven time intervals? in FacetGrid function

Tags: python, seaborn, facet-grid, line-plot

I made a line chart with seaborn FacetGrid, x-axis is the column called "dato", it is indicating the date of taking samples.

I have unequal time intervals between every sample taking, thereby I want to have corresponding space between every tick on x axis. how can I do that?

and I have a problem with making the correct order for dates also, tried some code, but not working for FacetGrid.

Here is my code and graph I made

```
mer=sns.FacetGrid(df, col='anlegg',hue='Merd',sharey=False,ylim=(0,4000))
sns.set_style('white')
sns.set_context('paper', font_scale=1.2)
mer.map_dataframe(sns.lineplot,x='dato',y='BW',marker='o',err_style='bars')
mer.add_legend()
mer.set_axis_labels('','BW')
mer.set_titles(col_template='anlegg {col_name}')
mer.set_xticklabels(rotation=90)
```

[image]

Comment: Can you add your sample dataframe?  - https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: `dato         uttak anlegg month Merd ID Length BW CF                             
              2020_12_15 12_20 KH Dec 3 1 31.0 370.0 1.241986 
2020_12_15 12_20 KH Dec 3 2 23.0 NaN NaN 0.0 
2020_12_15 12_20 KH Dec 3 3 32.0 410.0 1.251221 `